# coding double sum in R

Tags: r

I would like to compute these to  quantities

```
a12=sum_(i from 1 to m)sum_(j1<j2)(I(X[i]>Y[j1] and X[i]>Y[j2]))

a13=sum_(j from 1 to n)sum_(i1<i2)(I(X[i1]>Y[j] and X[i2]>Y[j]))
```

where I is the indicator function.

So I came up with this R code

```
a12=0; a13=0

for (l in 1:(length(Z1)-1)){

 for (m in  1:(length(Z2)-1)){

 a12<-a12+(Z1[l]<Z2[m])*(Z1[l+1]<Z2[m])*1

 a13<-a13+(Z1[l]<Z2[m])*(Z1[l]<Z2[m+1])*1

        } # closing m

          } # closing l

    a12=a12+sum((Z1[-length(Z1)]<Z2[length(Z2)])*(Z1[-1]<Z2[length(Z2)])*1)

    a13=a13+sum((Z1[length(Z1)]<Z2[-length(Z2)])*(Z1[length(Z1)]<Z2[-1])*1)


a12;
a13
```

Unfortunately, not only this is very slow but I am not getting what I am supposed to get.

Could you help me, please!

Thanks,

Roland

Comment: Examples of `Z1` and `Z2` and the result you expect would help.

Comment: Also explain your double sum better. j1 and j2 are only defined **after** you use them in a12. What is it exactly you want to do? A link to a paper or a better formed formula would help as well.

Comment: @Joris I think `Sum_(j1 < j2)` means "sum over all distinct pairs of indices `j1` and `j2`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming (for `a12`) you want to do the following. You have two vectors `x` (of length `m`) and `y`, and for each element `x[i]` of `x`, you are calculating the number of distinct 
index pairs `j1`, `j2` of `y` such that `x[i]` exceeds both `y[j1]` and `y[j2]`, and then you are summing this quantity over all `i`. 
Here's a fast way to do `a12` (the other will be left as an exercise). First note that you can flip the order of summation:

```
a12 = Sum_(j1 < j2) Sum_(i=1:m) I( X[i] > Y[j1] & X[i] > Y[j2] ),
```

i.e. for each distinct index-pair `j1,j2`, we calculate the number of `x` elements that exceed both `y[j1]` and `y[j2]`, and then we sum this quantity over all these distinct index-pairs. Now calculating the inner sum for pairs `j1,j2` is like a matrix multiplication. Indeed, suppose we define vectors `x` and `y`:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(1:5,5,T)
y <- sample(1:5,10,T)
```

then we can use the `outer` function to produce a matrix `y_x` whose `[i,j]` entry is TRUE if and only if `y[i] < x[j]`:

```
y_x <- outer(y,x,FUN = '<')
```

Now we get the inner sums by doing

```
z <- y_x %*% t(y_x)
```

where `z[i,j]` is the number of elements of `x` that exceed both `y[i]` and `y[j]`. Since we only want to sum `z[i,j]` for distinct `i < j`, we get the final result by taking the sum of the lower-triangle of `z` using

```
a12 <- sum( z[lower.tri( z )])

> a12
[1] 72
```